# R Bioconductor package error on Linux (GenomicFeatures)

Tags: r, error-handling, bioconductor

I want to use the function "makeTxDbfromGFF", which is part of the GenomicFeatures package. This function used to work perfectly until now, I get the following output:

```
makeTxDbFromGFF("/file/to/gencode.v19.annotation.gtf", dataSource="Gencode", organism="Homo sapiens", format="gtf")

>Import genomic features from the file as a GRanges object ... OK
>Prepare the 'metadata' data frame ... OK
>Make the TxDb object ... Error in c(x, value) : 
   could not find symbol "recursive" in environment of the generic function
```

This function works on my Mac, but not on my Linux workstation. Here some details to my session:

```
 R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
 Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

I already uninstalled the new version 1.26.3 and installed the previous version (1.24.5), but I get the same error. On my Mac I use the version 1.26.2.

My research so far was not very successful. I just found out it might be due to some inconsistency with other software/packages(?).

Comment: Perhaps, you could ask this question for [Bioconductor support sites](https://support.bioconductor.org/) , where your question will get more attention.

Comment: Answered here: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/93347/#93373